# Python xPath: How to get values in Iteration?

Tags: python, xpath

I am fetching a list from [here](http://cityinsider.com/biz/searchbiz_cityinsider.php?page=1&sort_by=1&srm=Stamps&loc=Mesa%2C%20AZ)

```
<div class="con">                    
                                                 <div style="float:left; width:100px; text-align:center; height:100px"><div class="photoBox" style=" overflow:hidden; width:84px; height:84px;"><a href="/b/mesa_az/1220832011"><img src="/theme/default/images/no_img/business/b__80x80"></a></div></div>
                              <div style="float:left; padding-left:10px; width:550px;">
                                <div style="float:left;"><h3><a href="/b/mesa_az/1220832011"><b>Stamps</b> Automotive Enterprises</a></h3> </div><div style="float:right;"><em>Rating:</em> <span style="color:#333; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">0</span> &nbsp; <img src="/theme/default/images/star/stars_00.gif" width="74" height="15"></div>

                                               <div id="clear">
                        <div style="float:left">
                        <a href="/c/mesa_az/locindustry/">Local Industry</a> / <a href="/c/mesa_az/locindustry/heavyconstruct/">Heavy Construction</a><br>
                                                                        <address>15001 S Power Rd # 1  <br>
                Mesa,  AZ 85212                   </address>
                  </div>
                                  <div style="float:right;"><h5>Click: 8 &nbsp;  Reviews: 0 </h5></div>




                               </div>
                              </div>

                    </div>
```

Now in Loop I have to search if there's  text *Cool Biz Name*, get it's URL

I am trying following but it's getting all links in each iteration:

```
b_list = tree.xpath('//*[@class="con"]')
    for biz in b_list:
        link = biz.xpath('//h3/text()')
        print(link)
```

How can I let `xPath` to traverse with respect to `DOM` within `biz`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner XPath has to start with a dot to be *context-specific*. Also, you need to use [`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) if you want to get the text of the node children as well:

```
b_list = tree.xpath('//*[@class="con"]')
for biz in b_list:
    link = biz.xpath('.//h3')[0].text_content()
    print(link)
```

You can also use `findtext()` method:

```
biz.findtext('h3')
```

Comment: It prints `[]` only.

Comment: I have updatred Question with Original HTML source as your solution is not working

Comment: @Volatil3 hey, is there still a problem applying the code in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Not at all! I sorted itout